# AngularJS + ng-repeat : weird $index and $parent.$index value when passing into a function

Tags: angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` inside another `ng-repeat`. In the second one, when I want to pass `$index` and `$parent.$index` to a function (using `ng-click` or `tooltip`), I don't get the correct indexes.

In order to get it work I need to use `$parent.$index` and `$parent.$parent.$index`.

What's weird is that I only need to do that for the second ng-repeat. Also the values seem only getting wrong when they are inside `ng-click` or `tooltip` (if I display them inside the ng-repeat they are correct)

I've made a plunker so you can see the result :
http://plnkr.co/edit/K6jWTffe8BqgLZhFIbHL?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@~3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.17" data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.17"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = [
          {id: "1", text: "text 1", more: [
            {id_more: "10", text_more: "text more 10"},
            {id_more: "11", text_more: "text more 11"},
            {id_more: "12", text_more: "text more 12"},
            {id_more: "13", text_more: "text more 13"},
          ]},
          {id: "2", text: "text 2", more: [
            {id_more: "20", text_more: "text more 20"},
            {id_more: "21", text_more: "text more 21"},
            {id_more: "22", text_more: "text more 22"},
            {id_more: "23", text_more: "text more 23"},
          ]},
          {id: "3", text: "text 3", more: [
            {id_more: "30", text_more: "text more 30"},
            {id_more: "31", text_more: "text more 31"},
            {id_more: "32", text_more: "text more 32"},
            {id_more: "33", text_more: "text more 33"},
          ]},
        ];

        $scope.func = function(index){
          var result = index;
          return result;
        };
        $scope.funcMore = function(index, indexMore){
          var result = index + ' - ' + indexMore;
          //The problem is when I want to do $scope.data[index].more[indexMore]
          //Then it throws error because some of the index are undefined in the array
          return result;
        };

        $scope.clickMore = function(index, indexMore){
          alert(index + ' - ' + indexMore);
        };

      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" style="margin:20px">
    <div ng-repeat="d in data" style="border:1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom:10px">
      {{d.id}} - {{d.text}} - {{$index}} - 
      <span tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-html-unsafe="{{func($index)}}">Working</span>
      <div ng-repeat="more in d.more" style="margin-left:20px">
        {{more.id_more}} - <!-- ID -->
        {{more.text_more}} - <!-- Text --> 
        ({{$parent.$index}} - {{$index}}) <!-- Correct $parent.$index and $index -->
        <span ng-click="clickMore($parent.$parent.$index, $parent.$index)" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-html-unsafe="{{funcMore($parent.$parent.$index, $parent.$index)}}">Working</span> - 
        <span ng-click="clickMore($parent.$index, $index)" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-html-unsafe="{{funcMore($parent.$index, $index)}}">Not Working</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for ng-init and ng-repeat.

With ng-init, you can alias $index so that you don't have the conflict you are seeing.  The example in the docs is almost exactly what you are trying to do.

From the docs:

```
<script>
  angular.module('initExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.list = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']];
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div ng-repeat="innerList in list" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
    <div ng-repeat="value in innerList" ng-init="innerIndex = $index">
       <span class="example-init">list[ {{outerIndex}} ][ {{innerIndex}} ] = {{value}};</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a modified Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/lW7ZU38zodjvbIFqvsdy?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand well, to pass the correct `$index` to my `ng-click` ot `tooltip` function I need to first `ng-init` a variable and pass that variable inside my `ng-click` ?

Comment: I added a modified Plunk that should clear it up for you

Comment: And to answer the question in your comment, yes - that should work.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for learning me this. I was very confused about this issue :)

Comment: @JoeEnzminger how should i use condition for `ng-show` inside innerList

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and the same answer worked for as well. The answerer does not explain why this happens though, does anybody know?

Comment: Each nested ng-repeat uses the same variable name "$index" on the same scope, so they end up clobbering each other.  ng-init allows you to create a new variable on the scope with a different name before the next nested instance of ng-repeat has a chance to overwrite the variable.